# Use of Indices while deriving the Inertia Tensor

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, tensor-calculus, notation

I'm trying to understand a derivation of the inertia tensor that is carried out for a rigid body rotating instantaneously about a point (the centre of mass):
$$\vec{L}=\int(\vec{r} \times \vec{v})dm=\int(\vec{r} \times (\vec{\omega}\times \vec{r}))dm=\int[(\vec{r}.\vec{r})\vec{\omega}-(\vec{r}.\vec{\omega})\vec{r}]dm$$ Further, $\omega^i=\Sigma_j\omega^j\delta^{ij}.$ Also, $\vec{r}.\vec{\omega}=\Sigma_ix^i\omega^i=\Sigma_ix^i\Sigma_j\omega_j \delta^{ij}=\Sigma_i \Sigma_jx^i\omega^j\delta^{ij}$.
Substituting this into the expression for the $i^{th}$ component of  $\vec{L}$, according to the derivation we get $\int[(\vec{r}.\vec{r})\Sigma_j\omega_j \delta^{ij}-x^i\Sigma_j\omega^jx^j]dm$. The next part of the derivation involves taking $\omega_j$ common from both terms inside the integral and further calling the other term the $ij^{th}$ component of the inertia tensor, something like this: $$L^i=\Sigma_j\omega_j\int[(\vec{r}.\vec{r}) \delta^{ij}-x^ix^j]dm, I^{ij}=\int[(\vec{r}.\vec{r}) \delta^{ij}-x^ix^j]dm$$
My question concerns the fact that $\Sigma_i \Sigma_jx^i\omega^j\delta^{ij}$ has been concluded to be $\Sigma_jx^j\omega^j$, which is fine, but further on in the derivation we require $\omega^j$ to be taken common, which we couldn't have done if the index were, say $k$ or $i$(which it actually could be, in this case since the summation order could be interchanged. Thus, this method doesn't make complete sense to me, because without the same indices one can't proceed. I understand this has less to do with physics and more with math, but in any case, I'm looking for an argument that would completely convince me that it indeed is okay to do this.

Comment: They are dummy indices, you can name them however you please. You are just factorizing by the $\omega_i$. You can try writing out the terms explicitly (only 9 terms) to better understand the algebraic manipulations if you’re unfamiliar with index notations.